# How to add unknown number of edittext on button click in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-button

In my android application, I have an edittext and below that there are two buttons. The first one is add button and another is send button. When user clicks on add button, then it should create another edittext just below the first one. This is fine if I have to create known number of edittexts and I can use for loop like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
    Edittext et= new Edittext(this);
    ll.addView(et);
}
```

But the problem is if user clicks multiple times then it should be insert multiple edtitexts there which is unknown. Means user can click 100's or 200's or more times. So don't know exactly how many times user will click that add button. Can anybody please help me to how to do this..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simple. Add one click listener and your job done. Hope it will help you.

```
Button addButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Edittext et= new Edittext(your_activity_name.this); //Replace with your activity name
       ll.addView(et);
    }
});
```